# WSL gives the error "The device is not connected"

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running the following version of windows.

```
Version 1909 (OS Build 18363.720)
```

I've enabled WSL using the commands provided on their official website. I've enabled WSL through the optional features window. I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using a setup I manually downloaded. When I was setting it up, it showed the error "Element not found" however the setup still finished.

When I try running the command wsl.exe or if I try opening the WSL-Remote extension of VS Code, it gives the following error.

```
C:\Users\ABC>wsl
The device is not connected.
```

The error that shows up in VS Code is as follows:

```
[2021-03-15 11:26:13.370] Resolving wsl+Ubuntu-20.04, resolveAttempt: 1
[2021-03-15 11:26:13.434] Starting VS Code Server inside WSL (Ubuntu-20.04)
[2021-03-15 11:26:13.435] Extension version: 0.54.3, Windows build: 18363. Multi distro support: available. WSL path support: enabled
[2021-03-15 11:26:13.435] No shell environment set or found for current distro.
[2021-03-15 11:26:13.573] Probing if server is already installed: C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu-20.04 -e sh -c "[ -d ~/.vscode-server/bin/fd6f3bce6709b121a895d042d343d71f317d74e7 ] && printf found || ([ -f /etc/alpine-release ] && printf alpine-; uname -m)"
[2021-03-15 11:26:13.665] Unable to detect if server is already installed: Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu-20.04 -e sh -c "[ -d ~/.vscode-server/bin/fd6f3bce6709b121a895d042d343d71f317d74e7 ] && printf found || ([ -f /etc/alpine-release ] && printf alpine-; uname -m)"
[2021-03-15 11:26:13.665] The device is not connected.
[2021-03-15 11:26:13.665] 
[2021-03-15 11:26:13.666] Launching C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu-20.04 sh -c '"$VSCODE_WSL_EXT_LOCATION/scripts/wslServer.sh" fd6f3bce6709b121a895d042d343d71f317d74e7 stable .vscode-server 5000  '}
[2021-03-15 11:26:13.724] The device is not connected.
[2021-03-15 11:26:13.724] 
[2021-03-15 11:26:13.725] VS Code Server for WSL closed unexpectedly.
[2021-03-15 11:26:13.725] For help with startup problems, go to
[2021-03-15 11:26:13.725] https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_wsl-tips
[2021-03-15 11:26:13.801] WSL Daemon exited with code 0
```

Additional Info: I've checked LxssManager and it is in running state.

Comment: Why did you not install Ubuntu for WSL using the Microsoft App Store?

Comment: I'm working in a restricted network environment (coorporate) so I'm not allowed to access the App Store.